# JQuery UI Slider Without Numbers

Tags: forms, jquery-ui, uislider

I am trying to build a rating form and want to use the JQuery UI increment slider except I don't want the value to be numbers, I'd like it to say something like "great" or "bad"

I'm great with HTML & CSS not so much with JavaScript or JQuery. I am taking a class in NYC next month to help me become more fluent in these languages. In the mean time any and all help is appreciated. I tried to hack other scripts I have found but keep running into problems. I ran into this script which is close to what I want, except the increments show #s.

I feel as if this code can be easily modified to do what I want.

http://jsfiddle.net/dmcgrew/EquTn/3/

```
<html>

<div class="kpa_rate kpa_rate1">
    <label for="kpa1_rating_value">Parking:</label>

    <div id="1" class="slider"></div>
    <input type="text" class="kpa1_rating_value" name="kpa1_rating" value="0" />       
</div>




<div class="kpa_rate kpa_rate2">
    <label for="kpa2_rating_value">Entrance:</label>

    <div id="2" class="slider"></div>
    <input type="text" class="kpa2_rating_value" name="kpa2_rating" value="0" />
</div>



</html>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
$(function() {
                $( ".slider" ).slider({
                  range: "max",
                  min: 0,
                  max: 5,
                  value: $("input", this).val(),
                  slide: function( event, ui ) {                    
                    //get the id of this slider
                    var id = $(this).attr("id");
                    //select the input box that has the same id as the slider within it and set it's value to the current slider value. 
                    $("span[class*=" + id + "]").text(ui.value);
                    $("input[class*=" + id + "]").val(ui.value);
                  }
                });
              });
</script>
```

Comment: _"I don't want the value to be numbers, I'd like it to say something like "great" or 'bad'"_ I'd start by making an array that maps the text to the values.

Comment: Did a little search into arrays and maping it. Don't understand it. Tried to teach myself Javascript and even checked out CodeAcademy. I finally caved and just signed up for a class. Hopefully I can pass this course can help me pass this hurdle.

Comment: What are the text values you want to use (aside from great and bad)?

Comment: very poor, so-so, moderate, great, outstanding .

Answer (score 1):

Did you want different words ("great, good, neutral, etc") for each value, or just good/bad at the ends?

If you want diff words for each of the 5 values, then like j08691 said, make an array that has the words you want at the indexes you want.

After this, replace the ui.value in .val(ui.value) with the array of value (Arr[ui.value]).
(I'm not sure you actually need the "span" part, but I don't do jquery, so I'm not sure).

```
$(function() {
         var Array = ["die","very bad", "bad", "neutral","good","great"];
            $( ".slider" )...etc
                             ...
$("input[class*=" + id + "]").val(Array[ui.value]);
```

This worked for me.

I did a bit of tinkering, and I think I've found a way to superficially solve your problem. Since the number inputted as the first value doesn't affect the slider button/thing, I'd say just put the first word that the slider should indicate (in my case, "die").
    
     //value does not equal a number here

In the next bit of code, just change input to Array[input], and you should be all set!
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    value: $("Array[input]"

I hope this works well enough for you.

Comment: Thank you. I will do my best. Sadly, I am not very good at JavaScript. Hence why I keep repeating I am attending class next month. all your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you! Worked great. Didn't think I could do it but with your help it worked. Much appreciated.

Comment: Ran into an issue. I was able to get the words to show up but now the initial shown value is a number. I tried to change the code where it says, value="2" but then the slider doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2984539 I added to my answer, and I hope it will do.